# File preview via a shared link

Tags: google-drive-api

I've got trouble with shared links pointing to ZIP files. Even though I am still able to download the ZIP file, I've got a message saying "A problem occurred with the file preview".
This message is displayed only when I am not authenticated and only with ZIP files in my case. If I am authenticated, the preview does work fine.

Anyway, to proceed with the download directly and not use the preview at all ?

D?

Comment: You want to download the shared zip files from Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, how much size are those files of?

Comment: You need to compromise a little bit I think. Using [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create), the pertinent file must be set to "anyone" of property "type".